# If condition on save laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had 2 tables. driver and part_time_available in the same form, when I select driver type = parttime, it'll show part_time_available field(day, start_time, end_time).

How to make condition if user choose fulltime. it didn't store part_time_available field to database.

here's my savehandler code so far :

```
public function saveHandler(Request $request, $obj)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
            $obj->fill($request->all());
            if (!$obj->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
            }
            foreach($request->parttimeAvailabilities as $pta) {
                \Log::info($pta);
                if (empty($pta['id'])) { 
                    $parttimeAvailability = new PartTimeAvailability();
                }
                else {
                    $parttimeAvailability = PartTimeAvailability::find($pta['id']);
                }
                $parttimeAvailability->driver()->associate($obj);
                $pta['driver_id'] = isset($pta['driver_id']);
                $parttimeAvailability->day = $pta['day'];
                $parttimeAvailability->start_time = isset($pta['start_time']) ? $pta['start_time'] : '00:00:00';
                $parttimeAvailability->end_time = isset($pta['end_time']) ? $pta['end_time'] : '00:00:00';
                $parttimeAvailability->available = isset($pta['available']);
                $parttimeAvailability->save();
            };
            $obj->save();
            if (!$parttimeAvailability->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($parttimeAvailability->errors());
            }
        DB::commit();
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->errors);
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, $e->errors);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request,'Unable to process. Please contact system Administrator');
    }

}
```

I mean before running foreach, it needs to check it's parttime or not.

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a condition before the whole foreach loop. such as:

```
if($request->get('driver_type') != 'full_time'){
 foreach loop
}
```